# How to use polymorphism with a list of lists in C#

Tags: c#, list, polymorphism, icollection

I am having trouble using polymorphism with a list of lists of `int` in C#. I need the "external" list to be able to add/remove "internal" lists, but the "internal" lists don't need to change. So I thought about using a variable type `ICollection<IEnumerable<int>>`.
Now, I now that this works:

```
IEnumerable<int> someList = new List<int>(); //Works fine
```

And I also now that this works:

```
ICollection<int> anotherList = new List<int>(); //Also works fine
```

However, I was surprised to know that this throws a compilation error:

```
ICollection<IEnumerable<int>> listOfLists = new List<List<int>>(); //Doesn't compile
```

> Cannot implicitly convert type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List>'
> to
> 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>'.
> An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

And I was also surprised to find out that this DOES compile fine:

```
IEnumerable<ICollection<int>> anotherListOfLists = new List<List<int>>(); //Works fine (?)
```

I know that a simple `List<List<int>> listOfListsWithoutPolymorphism = new List<List<int>>();` would work, but my questions are:

1. What are the differences between the 3rd and the 4th examples?
2. How could I implement what I need (something like `ICollecion<IEnumerable<int>>`) using polymorphism?

Comment: so `ICollection<IEnumerable<int>> listOfLists = new List<IEnumerable<int>>();`  work fine too?

Comment: `ICollection<IEnumerable<int>> test = new List<IEnumerable<int>>();` Compiles fine, so then you could add different types: `test.Add(new List<int>());` `test.Add(new ObservableCollection<int>());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to do with *variance* of the **actual** *interface* and not the *variance* of what the *interface* implements.

Let's refresh:

- Covariance permits a method to have a more derived return type than that defined by the generic type parameter of the interface
- Inversely, an invariant interface doesn't allow a more derived type

The interface signatures in your example:

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable {}

public interface ICollection<T> : IEnumerable<T> {}
```

Let's make easier to see with a contrived example:

```
public interface ICovariant<out T> { }

public interface IInvariant<T> : ICovariant<T> { }

public class SomeClass<T> : IInvariant<T> { }
```

**Tests**

```
// works because `SomeClass` implements IInvariant, type parameters are the same
IInvariant<int> test1 = new SomeClass<int>(); 

// works because SomeClass implements IInvariant which implements ICovariant, type parameters are the same
ICovariant<int> test2 = new SomeClass<int>();

// works because SomeClass implements IInvariant, type parameters are the same
IInvariant<ICovariant<int>> test3 = new SomeClass<ICovariant<int>>();

// works because IInvariant implements ICovariant, type parameters are the same
ICovariant<IInvariant<int>> test4 = new SomeClass<IInvariant<int>>();

// works because ICovariant is covariant and SomeClass implements IInvariant
// remembering Covariance permits a more derived type 
ICovariant<IInvariant<int>> test6 = new SomeClass<SomeClass<int>>();

// hold up, this does not work
// IInvariant is invariant and the type parameters are different!
// an Invariant interface doesn't allow a more derived type
IInvariant<ICovariant<int>> test5 = new SomeClass<SomeClass<int>>();
```